# Change the meaning of code by replacement of forward declaration with include

Tags: c++, include, forward-declaration

[Google C++ Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html) states that

> In extreme cases, replacing an #include with a forward declaration can silently change the meaning of code.

Can you please help me to find some examples?

Comment: I can't think of any cases where this turns a valid program into another valid program with a different meaning. But it can easily lead to the program silently exhibiting undefined behavior. E.g. "**5.3.5/5** If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you please convert your comment to an answer, ideally with a small code sample?

Comment: whenever it matters whether a type is complete or not it makes a difference.

Comment: It's simple, really: `class C; void f(C* p) { delete p; /* ~C doesn't run */}`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is still a comment, not an answer:)

Comment: I don't think my gut feeling qualifies as an answer. Just because I can't think of any such cases doesn't mean they don't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two cases.  One of them is UB, the other I think is defined change of behavior (assuming no ODR or similar violations: ie, no call to `foo` ever sees the definition of `A`, but I am uncertain)

```
namespace N {
  struct B {};
  struct A;//:B{};
}

void foo(N::B*){
  std::cout << "B\n";
}
template<class T, class=std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible<T*,N::B*>{}>>
void foo(T*){
  std::cout << "T\n";
}

int main() {
  foo( (N::A*)0 );
}
```

replacing `struct A;` with `struct A:B{};` will change which of the `foo` overloads are called.

In addition, `delete A;` will call `~A()` if its is visible when `delete A;` is called.  Otherwise, if there is a non-trivial destructor, we have UB.  In this case, the meaning of the code changes in that it goes from UB to DB, which is I suppose a change of meaning.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most insidious examples I'm aware of is the C-style cast in conjunction with inheritance.

Say you have:

```
class Parent1 {};
class Parent2 {};

class Child : public Parent1, public Parent2 {};
```

Then in some other file You cast from Parent2 to child:

```
Parent2* parent2_ptr = new Child;
Child* obj = (Child*)parent2_ptr;
```

With the full definition the C-style cast is a `static_cast`, correctly fixing up the address. With a forward declaration (of Child) the C-style cast becomes a `reinterpret_cast` silently breaking the code.